# Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a worksheet with data similar to the following:

```
P1_ShipType         P2_ShipType         RoundTime
Kus_AssaultFrigate  Tai_AssaultFrigate  117
Kus_AssaultFrigate  Tai_AttackBomber    17
Kus_AssaultFrigate  Tai_Carrier         1191
Kus_AttackBomber    Tai_AssaultFrigate  2775
Kus_AttackBomber    Tai_AttackBomber    18
Kus_AttackBomber    Tai_Carrier         0
Kus_Carrier         Tai_AssaultFrigate  1354
Kus_Carrier         Tai_AttackBomber    8
Kus_Carrier         Tai_Carrier         0
```

How do I "pivot" the table such that it looks like this:

```
                    Tai_AssaultFrigate      Tai_AttackBomber        Tai_Carrier
Kus_AssaultFrigate  117                     17                      1191
Kus_AttackBomber    2775                    18                      0
Kus_Carrier         1354                    8                       0
```

Thanks!

[edit]

But what if there are multiple columns per RoundTime?

```
P1_ShipType             P1_Research     P2_ShipType             P2_Research     RoundTime
Kus_AssaultFrigate      guns            Tai_AssaultFrigate      guns            48
Kus_AssaultFrigate      guns            Tai_AttackBomber        guns            11
Kus_AssaultFrigate      guns            Tai_Carrier             guns            38
Kus_AttackBomber        guns            Tai_AssaultFrigate      guns            62
Kus_AttackBomber        guns            Tai_AttackBomber        guns            70
Kus_AttackBomber        guns            Tai_Carrier             guns            69
Kus_Carrier             guns            Tai_AssaultFrigate      guns            5
Kus_Carrier             guns            Tai_AttackBomber        guns            84
Kus_Carrier             guns            Tai_Carrier             guns            77
Kus_AssaultFrigate      guns            Tai_AssaultFrigate      engines         83
Kus_AssaultFrigate      guns            Tai_AttackBomber        engines         82
Kus_AssaultFrigate      guns            Tai_Carrier             engines         29
Kus_AttackBomber        guns            Tai_AssaultFrigate      engines         97
Kus_AttackBomber        guns            Tai_AttackBomber        engines         22
Kus_AttackBomber        guns            Tai_Carrier             engines         10
Kus_Carrier             guns            Tai_AssaultFrigate      engines         71
Kus_Carrier             guns            Tai_AttackBomber        engines         3
Kus_Carrier             guns            Tai_Carrier             engines         38
Kus_AssaultFrigate      engines         Tai_AssaultFrigate      guns            34
Kus_AssaultFrigate      engines         Tai_AttackBomber        guns            21
Kus_AssaultFrigate      engines         Tai_Carrier             guns            84
Kus_AttackBomber        engines         Tai_AssaultFrigate      guns            51
Kus_AttackBomber        engines         Tai_AttackBomber        guns            73
Kus_AttackBomber        engines         Tai_Carrier             guns            27
Kus_Carrier             engines         Tai_AssaultFrigate      guns            66
Kus_Carrier             engines         Tai_AttackBomber        guns            82
Kus_Carrier             engines         Tai_Carrier             guns            22
Kus_AssaultFrigate      engines         Tai_AssaultFrigate      engines         10
Kus_AssaultFrigate      engines         Tai_AttackBomber        engines         63
Kus_AssaultFrigate      engines         Tai_Carrier             engines         2
Kus_AttackBomber        engines         Tai_AssaultFrigate      engines         94
Kus_AttackBomber        engines         Tai_AttackBomber        engines         44
Kus_AttackBomber        engines         Tai_Carrier             engines         93
Kus_Carrier             engines         Tai_AssaultFrigate      engines         5
Kus_Carrier             engines         Tai_AttackBomber        engines         53
Kus_Carrier             engines         Tai_Carrier             engines         80
```

Here is what the result should look like:

```
                                                Tai_AssaultFrigate      Tai_AttackBomber        Tai_Carrier     Tai_AssaultFrigate      Tai_AttackBomber        Tai_Carrier
                                                guns                    guns                    guns            engines                 engines                 engines
Kus_AssaultFrigate  guns                        117                     17                      1191            117                     17                      1191
Kus_AttackBomber    guns                        2775                    18                      0               2775                    18                      0
Kus_Carrier         guns                        1354                    8                       0               1354                    8                       0
Kus_AssaultFrigate  engines                     117                     17                      1191            117                     17                      1191
Kus_AttackBomber    engines                     2775                    18                      0               2775                    18                      0
Kus_Carrier         engines                     1354                    8                       0               1354                    8                       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siply you can select data range and then in excel;

```
Insert--> Pivot Table.
```

Then select the data fields like below.

```
Row Lables --> P1_ShipType
Column LAble -->P2_ShipType
Values --> Round Time
```

Please refer screen-shots

[image: Pivot Table]

[image: Output]

[image: FOrmatting and Total Removed]

Pivot Table can be re-arranged as you want with avialable columns.
Here is one sample.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do it without the fancy formatting and grand totals? I just want plain data.

Comment: Formatting and Grand total comes with pivot option. Do you have thosands of raw data? If not you can just copy and paste this output in plain text format.

Comment: Yes I have a lot of data. Would this be easier to do in Access?

Comment: You can remove the formatting by using design tab.  The for the 'Grand Total' in Design Tab there is a lable called "Grand Totals" there select "off for raws and columns"

Comment: Is it possible to simulate a multi-column primary key? What if P1_ShipType and P2_ShipType each had a second column such as P1_Research and P2_Research to distinguish them from similar items?

Comment: Your second column can be displayed as sub columns in pivot table. Please provide some sample data

Comment: I edited my first post with another sample.